# Bidirectional Long Short Term Memory (BiLSTM)

Tags: lstm

I am learning about the variant of LSTM.

Can someone explained the numerical example about Bidirectional LSTM to me like the article below?

[LSTM Numerical Example](https://medium.com/@aidangomez/let-s-do-this-f9b699de31d9)

Thank you.

Comment: What part are you confused by? What is your understanding of it? What doesn’t make sense?

Comment: Hello @JeremyCaney.

Thank you for your response.

I need the numerical example of Bidirectional LSTM.

The one that make I confuse is how can we merge the output of the forward layer and backward layer?

Thank you.